# Can shopify do this? (what is best platform?)

Tags: shopify

My clients need to send me a file that we will edit and send back to them (ideally through a client page). Is Shopify a good platform for this kind of business? I know it is well suited for digital goods but I haven't seen anything that would allow uploading a custom file to an order during fulfillment.

EDIT
ok for file uploads that was easy enough to find, but how to provide a link to a different file for each client that bought the same product? After the file has been edited ideally we would put the file somewhere (dropbox?) and have a link available on the client account page and in a fulfillment confirmation email. 
the only thing I have found so far would be through metafields and [custom fields](http://freakdesign.com.au/pages/shopify-custom-fields) added to each order. Its a bit annoying to have to use chrome plugin to show the custom fields on the order dashboard. It would be nice if a customfield would be added automatically to each order. Then a link to the file in dropbox could be added to the order using an ipad and the clients would have instant access.

Why the two down votes? I have searched a long time and the only workaround I can find is hardly satisfactory. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I think [this shopify app](https://apps.shopify.com/custom-fields-2)  might do the trick but it seems expensive for one field added to the order dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely let your customers upload files when they buy from your Shopify store.  Check out this tutorial for more information on how to set this up with line item properties: https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/get-customization-information-for-products#allow-file-uploads